# Select e insert de datos php

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

Chicos una duda tengo estos datos

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "
Select a.fecha_y_hora, a.usuario 
from jos2p_fb_contact_sample_repeat_cursos as b 
inner join jos2p_fb_contact_sample as a on a.id = b.parent_id 
where b.cursos=53";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {   
        $usuario = $row["usuario"];
        $fecha = $row["fecha_y_hora"];
        echo "" . $usuario. 
             " "  . $fecha. "<br>";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO actividades 
        (id, date_time, actividad, usuario_actividad)
         VALUES (NULL,'$fecha', '["1"]', '$usuario')";
         var_dump($sql);
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New records created successfully";
        } else 
        {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }   
    } 
    else 
    {
    echo "0 results";
    }
$conn->close();
?>
```

*Ya tengo el while la duda es como hacer un insert a una tabla en la misma base de datos pero con los datos que acabo de seleccionar por favor me ayudan sé muy poco de php y no encuentro como hacerlo :(*

La tabla donde voy a guardar los datos seleccionados tiene 4 campos pero yo puedo poner los campos sólo que no se como hacer el insert y el ciclo de lo que obtuve en el select

UPDATE 1:
el error que manda ahora es este Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER)   on line 28 exactamente en el insert

Comment: ¿Qué datos son los que quieres insertar en la base de datos? ¿qué es lo que no sabes hacer, una consulta tipo INSERT o ejecutarla desde php?

Comment: quiero insertar los datos que traigo desde la consulta de select y luego insertarlos en una tabla distinta en la base de datos, la consulta la se hacer el problema es como se hace con php

Comment: si tu id es pk en tu base de datos y el mismo esta autoincrementando por default, te recomiendo sacar  en el INTO id y en el value NULL, la fecha ¿ en que formato tienes en base de datos? y ¿ en que formato estas seteando en el query?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar variables para luego ser insertadas, ejemplo

```
$usuario = $row["usuario"];
$fecha = $row["fecha_y_hora"];
```

Estas ya pueden ser usadas despues por fuera del `while` en un `insert`

ejemplo

```
INSERT INTO users (user, fecha) values ($usuario, $fecha)
```

Comment: Entonces pongo así el código?if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
 {
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     {
         echo "" . $row["fecha_y_hora"]. 
                 " "  . $row["usuario"]. "<br>";

  }
  $usuario = $row["usuario"];
  $usuario = $row["fecha_y_hora"];
 }